# Navigate inside UserControl

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm working on a application where I load a XAML page inside a usercontrol,
depending on which menu item was clicked.

After figuring out how to load in XAML page in a XAML page (using usercontrol), I'm running into the next problem: Navigation.

I added a picture to illustrate what I'm working on.
[image: blueprint]

When you launch the app, you see the left state (state open), where the menu is presented and a little bit of the content on the right.
If you click the red button, the page scrolls to a "full screen" of the right state (state closed). This is still the same page, the MainPage.xaml, but with a new page loaded in the usercontrol. Let's say the loaded page is news, where you can select an article by clicking.

This all works great.

The problem is, when I try to use the navigationservice to see a detail of the news, the app fails. (it does work when I set the news page as start page, but it won't work inside the usercontrol).

I tried fixing this by the following code:

```
NewsDetail detailpage = new NewsDetail();
this.Content = detailpage;
```

Actually, this works.. but then I can no longer pass a querystring to load a certain article on the page.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static variable in App.xaml.cs when querystrings become useless.

just declare a static variable of type say string in app.xaml.cs

```
public static string MyString;
```

just assign it a value before navigation

```
App.MyString="Hello";
```

And get this value where ever you want to get it.

```
string ss=App.MyString;
```

Comment: But.. also introduces the next problem :)
I can't use the back button, but I'm not able to override the back button to handle behavior either.

I still have the feeling my workflow is incorrect. Any suggestions?

Comment: setting a static variable stopped back button to work? Could you share me with what you are doing there?

Comment: My entire app works on one page, other pages are loaded in the usercontrol. I guess I can't override the back button because of this certification:
(5.2.4.2) Pressing the Back button from the first screen of an app must close the app.

I'll try making some landingpage, showing that for a short period of time. That was my app no longer sits in the first page, and maybe it makes overriding the back button possible?

Comment: Yes, A single paged app wont allow you to override its back button, allowed overrides could be a message asking you to confirm exit. But, if back button protects app from getting exited then it is not allowed.

Comment: Do you have an idea for a better way to fix my problem? (the navigating inside a usercontrol). Am I missing something?